# I have to put switching keyboard menu like apple keyboard in my custom keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keyboard, custom-keyboard

- i have to put switching keyboard menu like apple keyboard in my custom keyboard.
- choose another keyboard from my keyboard on click on globe button same like apple keyboard.
- If possible then please explain how can i access these keyboard of apple in my custom keyboard app.

[image]

Comment: Did you read through ***"Providing a Way to Switch to Another Keyboard"*** on this page of Apple's docs [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH16-SW4) ?